# I can't receive emails with Foxmail, but the email has been received locally

Tags: postfix, postgresql, dovecot

Maillog doesn't show any errors. I see a new email in my /home/mail/domain/www3/new. I just can't read the email by using the client or telnet 110/143. Dovecot info The log doesn't seem to show any errors. I don't know what to do. Everything shows that there seems to be no problem.
/etc/postfix/main.cf have some configurations：

```
ssqueue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
virtual_uid_maps = static:200 
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_alias_maps.cf 
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_domains_maps.cf 
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf 
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/mail 
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/relay_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000 
virtual_minimum_uid = 8
virtual_transport = virtual 
local_transport = virtual 
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
```

dovecot.conf have some configurations：

```
dict {
#quota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
 #expire = sqlite:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}
!include conf.d/*.conf
mail_location = maildir:/home/mail/%u/
namespace inbox {
  type = private
  inbox = yes
  location =
mailbox Drafts {
  special_use = \Drafts
}
mailbox Junk {
  special_use = \Junk
}
mailbox Sent {
  special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox "Sent Messages" {
  special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox Trash {
  special_use = \Trash
}
prefix =
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
ssl = no
login_greeting = mail.xxxxxx.com
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
service auth {
  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
  # Auth process is run as this user.
  user = postfix
  group = postfix
}
service imap {
    executable = imap
}
userdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
passdb {
    driver = sql
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
}
first_valid_uid = 200 
mail_uid = 200 
mail_gid = 12
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib
plugin {
    zlib_save_level = 6
    zlib_save = gz
}
protocol imap {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_zlib
}
 mail_max_userip_connections = 50
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
```

dovecot-sql.conf have some configurations：

```
driver = pgsql
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=xxxxxxxx
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
password_query = SELECT username AS user,password FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' 
AND active='1'
user_query = SELECT '/home/mail/' || maildir AS home, 200 as uid, 12 as gid FROM 
mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

virtual_mailbox_maps or others like this:

```
user = postfix
password = xxxxxxxx
hosts = localhost
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = true
```

Other configurations should be irrelevant.Can anyone help me, because all the information seems to indicate that they are normal, but I can't get the expected results.Thanks.By the way, I can use Foxmail to send mail.
maillog:

```
Mar 31 15:33:40 mail postfix/master[28261]: daemon started - 
version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar 31 15:33:58 mail postfix/smtpd[28327]: connect from 
xmbg7.mail.xx.com[101.91.43.51]
Mar 31 15:33:58 mail postfix/smtpd[28327]: D0F0D1413AC: 
client=xmbg7.mail.xx.com[101.91.43.51]
Mar 31 15:33:59 mail postfix/cleanup[28335]: D0F0D1413AC: 
message-id=<tencent_D9E32A8B5B16629BCC935B64F05261DABE06@xx.com>
Mar 31 15:33:59 mail postfix/qmgr[28263]: D0F0D1413AC: from= 
<xxx@xx.com>, size=2746, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 31 15:33:59 mail postfix/virtual[28337]: D0F0D1413AC: to= 
<www8@xx.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.26, 
delays=0.24/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to 
maildir)
```

Mar 31 15:33:59 mail postfix/qmgr[28263]: D0F0D1413AC: removed

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot searches for your e-mail in *mail_location*+username

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/mail/%u/
```

The normal behavior of postfix *virtual* delivery agent is to store them in *virtual_mailbox_base*+domain+username ([documentation here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html)) just like you mentioned:

```
I see a new email in my /home/mail/domain/www3/new
```

Using postfix *virtual* as delivery agent is not very practical. It lacks one of the most critical features: quota.

I suggest you use dovecot *lmtp* as delivery agent instead since dovecot lmtp has far more features.

If you still want to keep using postfix *virtual* delivery agent make sure your user_query takes in consideration the 'domain' part of the maildir location.

Comment: i just changed SELECT '/home/mail/' || maildir AS home to As mail ，it can receive the mail